# Update svg radialGradient with css variables

Tags: css, vue.js, svg, css-variables, radial-gradients

I have an svg image injected into a page using vue-svg-inline-loader.

```html
<img
  svg-inline
  src="@/assets/vectors/silhouettes/body.svg"
  :style="silhouetteStyle">
```

The svg contains a radialGradient that I modified to work with css variables as following

```xml
<defs>
  <radialGradient
    id="gradient"
    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    cx="50%"
    cy="27%"
    r="var(--radius)">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="var(--in-color)" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="var(--out-color)" />
  </radialGradient>
</defs>
```

In vue I update the css variables to create a dynamic gradient

```js
computed: {
  silhouetteStyle() {
    /* whatever the calculation of variables */
    return `--radius:${radius}; --in-color:${inColor}; --out-color:${outColor}`;
  },
},
```

Gradient colors are updated perfectly, but not the radius. I can't find any response out there about if it is even possible.

**-EDIT-**

Here is a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/morning-meadow-vvl5d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to illustrate the thing. As you can see colors are changed but not the radius

Comment: are you sure the color is updating? it should not like radius since CSS variable aren't supposed to work with attribute

Comment: @Kaiido yes but does the syntax of attribute allow CSS variables? They are matched to CSS properties but as far as I know the syntax isn't exactly the same (we cannot for example use !important inside attribute)

Comment: I updated the question, including a codesandbox demo illustrating that the colors are changing, but not the radius.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that would work... So your problem would be that the <circle>'s `r` is a [presentation-attribute](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#TermPresentationAttribute) but not the <radial-gradient>'s one. You can't use CSS to set it.

Comment: Any alternative? Having in mind that in the real world example the svg is not inline but injected from a svg file, so attributes can not be binded to vue computed properties (that's why I tried to use css variables)

Comment: You mean from an <img>? Then that won't work anyway, you can't access the document loaded from an <img>, not with js, not with css, not even from dev-tools. Since it doesn't allow user interaction nor scripting from inside either, you won't even be able to embed your <input> there.

Comment: Use SMIL to create a dynamic gradient. Although you'll need to have one gradient per distinct pair of colours.